# Почему код, при добавлении фигурных скобок в тело стрелочной функции возвращает undefined?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему этот код возвращает все верно:

```
const isArrayEmpty = (inputArray) =>
inputArray.length > 0 ? 'Массив не пустой' : 'Массив пустой'

console.log(isArrayEmpty([1, 3]))
console.log(isArrayEmpty([]))
```

А вот этот код, просто при добавлении фигурных скобок в тело стрелочной функции возвращает undefined?

```
const isArrayEmpty = (inputArray) => {
inputArray.length > 0 ? 'Массив не пустой' : 'Массив пустой';
}

console.log(isArrayEmpty([1, 3]));
console.log(isArrayEmpty([]));
```

Comment: Ну вы посмотрите правила написания стрелочных функций и всё...В документации чётко они написаны

Comment: Grundy в своём репертуаре. Закрыл как дубликат на вопрос, где проблема совсем другая...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, надо смотреть не только заголовок.

Comment: @Grundy То, что в другом ответе есть упоминание действий, которые могут ответить на текущий вопрос не делает его дубликатом

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в ответе есть объяснение ошибки и решение - это очевидный дубликат ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy Тогда заголовок должен быть соответствующий, а не так, что на вопрос "почему не тает сугроб" ответ "надо взять лопату и убрать"

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, неверная аналогия.

Comment: Во втором варианте ты не добавил `return`. Т.о. получается что твоя функция ничего не возвращает явно, тогда делается не явный возврат `undefined`...

Comment: Спасибо мужики.